# How to do a get request and get the same results that a browser would with Nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to do a get request for image search, and I'm not getting the same result that I am in my browser. Is there a way to get the same result using node.js?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
var keyword = "Photographie"
keyword = keyword.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9éàèùâêîôûçëïü]/g, "+")

var httpOptions = { hostname: 'yandex.com', 
                    path: '/images/search?text=' + keyword, //path does not accept spaces or dashes
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}}

console.log(httpOptions.hostname + httpOptions.path +postTitle)

https.get(httpOptions, (httpResponse) => { 
    console.log(`STATUS: ${httpResponse.statusCode}`);
    httpResponse.setEncoding('utf8');
    httpResponse.on('data', (htmlBody) => {
        console.log(`BODY: ${htmlBody}`);
    });
});
```

Comment: Care to give us a hint as to what is different?

Comment: Everything, they detect that I'm not a browser and show no results for anything.

Comment: You'll have to be a LOT more specific about what you see when you request the content in node.js and what you see when you fetch the contents in a browser.  For example, if the page is rendered via client-side Javascript, then you will need a browser-like environment to load and run the page in to get the desired content.  If the server you are requesting it from is just detecting you don't have a browser user agent, then you may just need to spoof the user agent in more detail.  We can't possibly know without a lot more info from you.

Comment: If they detect you're not a browser, try changing `User-Agent` header to something that looks like a browser user agent

Comment: @jfriend00 it says "looks like the search requests sent from your IP address are automated.", and it's not because I did it too many times, I got that on my first try.

Comment: There's no generic answer to that.  You will have to study what a request looks like from a browser (you can use the network tab in the Chrome browser debugger) to see exactly what that request looks like and you will just have to make your request so it is indistinguishable from that.  It could be headers, cookies, timing, etc... that the host site is looking at.  It's a debugging exercise that is extremely specific to that web site where you try things and learn.  Nothing we can really do from here.

Answer (score 0):

By switching to the request-promise library and using the proper capitalization of the User-Agent header name and an actual user agent string from the Chrome browser, this code works for me:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
let keyword = "Photographie"

let options = { url: 'http://yandex.com/images/search?text=' + keyword,
                headers: {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'}
    };

rp(options).then(response => { 
    console.log(response);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

When I try to run your actual code, I get a 302 redirect and a cookie set.  I'm guessing that they are expecting you to follow the redirect and retain the cookie.  But, you can apparently just switch to the above code and it appears to work for me.  I don't know exactly what makes my code work, but it could be that is has a more recognizable user agent.

Comment: @DanyM - Did this answer your question?